# Android Studio autocomplete for java.util.* classes is gone

Tags: android, android-studio

For every class inside java.util.* package, the autocomplete not working properly.

[image: autocomplete android studio]

But, if I manually write "import java.util.List" works, any idea why of this behaviour?

**FIXED**:

For any reason this package is listed in:

[image]

So, the solutions is remove of this exclusion list.

edit: add infos about version

Android Studio 3.1 Canary 8
Build #AI-173.4529993, built on January 5, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12

Comment: Have you tried invalidate caches & restart?

Comment: yes... but no changes.

Comment: Canary channel is less stable, they may have bugs, use stable channel